# Swift error extending Dictionary Any? is not convertible to Profiles

Tags: swift

I am getting an error: 'Any?' is not convertible to 'Profiles' I am not sure how to correct. I am trying to extend the dictionary. I am needing the structure show in the Profile Struct

```
struct Profiles {
  var id: Int
  var name: String
}

extension NSDictionary {

  var profileDictionary: [String : Profiles] {
    var dictionary: [String : Profiles] = [:]
    let keys = self.allKeys.compactMap { $0 as? String }
    for key in keys {
      let keyValue = self.value(forKey: key) as Profiles
      dictionary[key] = keyValue
    }
    return dictionary
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure why you need to use `NSDictionary` when coding with Swift. I will post the Dictionary approach but `NSDictionary` would be exactly the same. You can use reduce method and convert all key value pairs to `(String, Profiles)` and add it to the resulting dictionary:

```
extension Dictionary {
    var profileDictionary: [String : Profiles] {
        reduce(into: [:], { result, keyValue in
            if let kv = keyValue as? (String, Profiles) {
                result[kv.0] = kv.1
            }
        })
    }
}
```